# Get REST response from parse.com for search functionality - PHP

Tags: php, curl, parse-platform

I'm creating a search functionality for my website and I'm using Parse.com for storing data. I have a class Posts with a "plainContent" column which stores the content of my article in plain text format. I've found this article:

> http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/implementing-scalable-search-on-a-nosql-backend/

which is very useful. I've added the cloud code which splits my plain text into single words and puts them into an array. Now I have my Posts with an extra column "words" which stores an array with all the single words for article's content. I got the the step of retrieving data now but the problem is the following code:

```
curl -v -X GET  
    -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: ${APPLICATION_ID}" 
    -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ${REST_API_KEY}" 
    -G 
    --data-urlencode 'where={"hashtags":{"$all":["#parse", "#ftw"]}}' 
    "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Post"
```

precisely the --data-urlencode row which in my case would be:

```
--data-urlencode 'where={"words":{"$all":["word1", "word2"]}}'
```

I can't create the curl query with PHP. What exactly is the $all variable in the example?
Here's my php script:

```
$url = 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Posts?';

$headers = array(
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "X-Parse-Application-Id: " . $MyApplicationId,
    "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: " . $MyParseRestAPIKey
);

$query = urlencode('where={"words":{"$all":["parseobjectcontains", "compatible"]}}');
$ch = curl_init($url.$query);

$handle = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($handle);
curl_close($handle);

$array = json_decode($data);

var_dump($array);
```

This script returns all results without filtering.

The question is how to build this sentence to reflect the example in the article from the link? What should be that $all variable?

```
$query = urlencode('where={"words":{"$all":["parseobjectcontains", "compatible"]}}');
```

> EDIT

I had an error in my script:

```
$ch = curl_init($url.$query);
$handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
```

Correction:

```
$handle = curl_init($url.$query);
    //$handle = curl_init();
    //curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
```

Comment: `$all` is not a php variable, its just a string with a dollar sign in it, used as part of the query syntax for mongodb

Comment: @steve not it's all clear about it. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `$all` is needed as it is you have shown in your code (as per parse.com). Here are few catch.

1) You are doing `urlencode` over the whole request parameter. But actually you have to do it over the value of `where` in your example. So change it as below:

```
$query = 'where='.urlencode('{"words":{"$all":["parseobjectcontains", "compatible"]}}');
```

2) The data you are posting here is not json, it is actually `key=value` pared data. So remove `Content-Type: application/json` thing from your code.

That's all!